# Подскажите модульную систему js

Tags: javascript, javascript-faq

Начал программировать на js, но опыта мало. Хотелось бы как на php иметь аналогию с классами. Чтобы писал в один файл модуль и потом его при необходимости подключал в файле. + Было бы преимуществом чтобы это потом можно было в 1 js файл компилировать. Подскажите пожалуйста какой фреймворк или библиотеку использовать под эти нужды? Или возможно какая то статья затрагивающая эту тему будет не лишней. Спасибо

Comment: вот ссылка на [хабр](https://habrahabr.ru/post/152833/)

Comment: Вот отличная статейка про модульность в ES - 2015 [ссыль](https://learn.javascript.ru/modules)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

В современной экосистеме JavaScript можно выделить несколько подходов к разбиению кода на модули:

1. **AMD** - формат описания модулей, используемый в [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/). На мой ( очень субъективный) взгляд описание модулей несколько избыточно. Одна из основных "фишек" - асинхронная динамическая загрузка модулей по требованию. Хотя, если не изменяет память, есть и возможность собрать весь код в один *пакет*. Пример описания AMD модуля:

   ```
   // Описание зависимостей
   define(['jquery', 'foo', 'bar'], function (jquery, foo, bar) {
       // Определение самого модуля
       return function () {};
   });
   ```
2. **Common.js** - подход, используемый, например, в [Node.js](https://nodejs.org) экосистеме. Типичный модуль имеет вид:

   ```
   // Импортируем зависимости
   var jquery = require('jquery'),
       foo = require('foo'),
       bar = require('bar');

   // Экспортируем тело модуля
   module.exports = function() {};
   ```
3. **UMD** - комбинированный подход, позволяющий описывать модули, работающие как в AMD инфраструктуре, так и в Common.js. Является ничем иным, как средством совместимости.
4. Модули **ES2015** - специальный синтаксис, введенный в стандарт ES2015 позволяющий разбивать код на модули. Пример модуля:

   ```
   // Импортируем зависимости
   import 'jquery' as $;
   import foo from 'foo';
   import bar from 'bar';

   // Экспортируем тело модуля
   export default function() {};
   ```

Плохая новость заключается в том, что *ни один* из подходов к описанию модулей не может работать в браузере напрямую. Вам в любом случае придется подключать некую стороннюю библиотеку для управления модулями. Для AMD - это [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/); для Common.js - [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) и другие; для ES2015 - это может быть связка [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) + [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) или что-то еще.

Для новых проектов я бы порекомендовал вам обратить внимание на ES2015 модули и на Common.js модули. Тому есть несколько причин:

- Экосистема Node.js использует Common.js модули. Используя систему сборки вроде [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) вы можете использовать npm модули. Это позволит вам писать код, который будет выполняться как на сервере, так и на клиенте.
- При использовании современных систем сборки вы сможете практически без проблем комбинировать модули ES2015 и Common.js
- Хотя сегодня в браузерах нет встроенных средств загрузки модулей ES2015, все идет к тому, что рано или поздно они появятся.

Что почитать:

- https://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/
- https://learn.javascript.ru/modules
- http://frontender.info/es6-modules/
- https://habrahabr.ru/post/181536/
- *Очевидно, есть и другие статьи по теме. Google расскажет вам о них лучше меня. =)*