# Как объединить в один файл проект с функциями require?

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-faq

Как объединить в один файл js несколько файлов в которых присутствует функция:

```
require('./main')
require('./result')
require('./solution')
```

После установки npm пакета на локальном сервере файлы правильно обрабатываются браузером. 
А когда цепляю `main.js` файл в котором присутствуют `require()` к html. То на другом сервере он пишет ошибки

> Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module:

Есть ли какие нибудь инструменты, чтобы получить один js файл где уже все зависимости включены на месте?

Нужно прицепить js код в файл на сервере где нельзя ставить node или что то подобное. То есть js должен обрабатываться чисто на клиенте и всё. Он ничего не должен подгружать.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Такие инструменты есть, и их много.

Этот класс инструментов называется "системы сборки". Суть их работы сводится к построении AST дерева по JS коду для поиска всех зависимостей и подмене `require` функций на специфичный для сборщика код. На выходе вы получаете один JavaScript файл, со всем вашим кодом (и зависимостями) внутри.

В качестве примера приведу пример использования двух популярных систем сборки: [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) и [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/). (Есть и другие, но про них Google расскажет вам лучше меня.)

**Browserify** появился раньше чем Webapack и решает несколько более узкий круг задач (см. описание Webpack ниже). Для глобальной установки достаточно выполнить команду:

```
npm install -g browserify
```

Для сборки проекта нужно выполнить:

```
browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

где `main.js` - точка входа вашего приложения, а `bundle.js` - имя результирующего файла.

**Webpack** в отличии от Browserify создавался не только для сбора JavaScript кода. Эта среда сборки расширяет применимость функции `require` позволяя вам использовать ее для подключения:

- картинок
- CSS файлов
- файлов, написанных для CSS препроцессоров (LESS/SASS/...)
- исходном коде на языках, компилируемых в JS (CoffeeScript и др.)
- шаблонов

Каждый тип зависимостей обрабатывается по своему в зависимости от конфигурации Webpack. На выходе вы получаете набор файлов, готовых к непосредственному подключению к HTML странице.

Если говорить только о JS приложениях, то Webpack может работать аналогично Browserify. Для глобальной установки вам достаточно выполнить команду:

```
npm install webpack -g
```

Для сборки проекта нужно выполнить:

```
webpack ./entry.js bundle.js
```

где `./entry.js` - точка входа вашего приложения, а `bundle.js` - имя результирующего файла.

**Замечание**

Дополнительно, вы можете почитать о распространенных модульных системах в JS в [другом моем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/503198/182771).