# Зависимости ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Обязателен ли NodeJS для ReactJS? И если да, то почему?

Comment: Нет, не обязателен.

Comment: У меня самая последняя версия браузера, и при этом пишет `Unexpected token import`.

Comment: @TimurMusharapov, es6-модули браузерами из коробки не поддерживаются. Но это проблема не реакта, а того что Вы пишете import React from 'react'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, не обязателен.

Просто в современном фронтенде npm - пакетный менеджер идущий в комплекте с нодой - стандарт де факто.

Но Вы вполне можете просто [загрузить React c cdn](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html#using-a-cdn), не разбираясь с пакетами.

Есть впрочем нюанс. ES6-модули (записи вида `import React from 'react'`), которые Вы пытаетесь использовать (и которые обычно используют в примерах), браузеры из коробки на данный момент не поддерживают. Чтобы это заработало, нужен этап препроцессинга, то есть нужна нода.

Библиотеки, загруженные с cdn предоставляются  в формате UMD-модулей.. То есть вам не надо никакие импорты писать, эти библиотеки сами создадут глобальные переменные `React` и `ReactDOM`.

Подробнее про то, какие модульные системы есть в js [можно почитать в этом ответе.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/503198/14963)