# Как в ReactJS организовать подключение компонента из другого файла?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Уважаемые знатоки React! Подскажите, как правильно организовать подключение и использование компонента, который хранится в отдельном файле? В примере ниже мне нужно внутри файла main.js использовать компонент Header, который хранится в файле componets/header.js

**Index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalize.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@0.6.2/build/pure.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.js"></script>

       <script src="/js/main.js" type="text/babel"></script>

  <title>Тайтл</title>

</head>
<body>

<div id="layout"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**/js/components/header.js:**

```
"use strict";

class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <header>This is Header</header>;
    }
}
```

**/js/main.js:**

```
'use strict';

import Header from 'components/header';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Header />,
    document.getElementById( 'layout' )
);
```

Comment: Так, кажется я ваш вопрос на эту тему уже видел. _Обычно_ с реактом используют систему es6 модулей (конструкции импорт-экспорт), но для этого надо настроить этап сборки. Без этого можно либо прикрутить любую другую систему модулей (не очень но можно) либо общаться через глобальную область видимости (вообще плохо).

Comment: Про то какие есть системы модулей, вот этот ответ: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503158/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-js

Comment: Короче, если вам для реального проекта а не поиграться, то рано или поздно придется настроить вебпак, если поиграться - то можно и через глобальные переменные пообщаться как предлагает @Mikl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае (вы не используете сборщики), подключайте файл с вашим компонентом через тег script:

```
<script src="/js/components/header.js" type="text/babel"></script>
```